# use normal action buttons as software keyboard keys

Tags: android

I would like to make a customized software keyboard which consist of normal action buttons instead of keys.

Normally, we can change the appearance of the software keyboard but the layout is already predefined in *Keyboard* class, with < Row > and < Key >. 
However I would like to use < Button > so that I can make weird style keyboard without the restriction of normal layout, such as making it look like waves or smiley.
Also, since it is a < Button >, an intent or special action could be attached to it.

Is it still doable under the *Keyboard* class, or do I have to make a completely new class?
Would appreciate any advice and guidance.

Comment: I assume you talk about IME? Your custom software keyboard layout can be anything you like (there're lot of keyboards in Google Play with variety of layouts). You definitely must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I agree. What I want to experiment with is using other than < Row > and < Key >, such as < Button >. Though I could probably get you wrong since I'm still learning to make one.